# Which interfaces do I need to configure to change MTU of Cisco Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, mtu, site-to-site

I have a number of Site-to-Site VPN tunnels in my network configurations. They are configured using Cisco ASA devices.

To resolve some performance issues I am trying to change the MTU for traffic through the VPN tunnel  to 1400. My question is: In order to change the MTU for traffic through the tunnel, which interface do I need to change the MTU on? Do I just need to change it for the Outside interface? Or do I also need to change it for the Inside/other interface(s)?

Comment: Is this running latest ASA version which supports VTI tunnel? If it is route based, we should be changing VTI mtu directly or do set tcp mss value(to a lower value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outside interface, but you need to be very careful with doing that, especially if you're setting the DF (don't fragment) bit rather than allowing fragmentation.   If you set the DF bit and then send larger packets than the MTU allows for, you're gonna drop packets and cause issues.  You will either need to make sure you're clearing the DF bit (to allow fragmentation) or make sure that you're only sending packets within your MTU range on both ends.

Comment: "_make sure that you're only sending packets within your MTU range on both ends._" Yes, use PMTUD, which is built in for IPv6 (assuming you have the proper ICMP allowed), but can be problematic for IPv4.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yep. Most tunnels are going to have the DF bit cleared, from my experience, but you can't always assume that's the case.

Comment: @JesseP. could you please clarify the comment about the DF bit. I'm aware of the concept, and some implementations (eg. using a windows `ping /f` command), but in the context of your answer where are you referring to? Based on these comments there is a setting somewhere in the Site-to-Site tunnel settings that controls this?

Comment: @Stringers Correct.  You control it on a global level, and the command is `crypto ipsec df-bit clear-df <interface>` in order to clear the bit, to **allow** fragmentation to take place if/when needed.

Comment: @JesseP. Ahh okay so similar to the MTU, this is an Interface-specific setting.

Comment: Yes.  It's also specific to IPsec traffic.  Aside from MTU, you might also want to look into MSS since that's NOT interface specific, and would accomplish your same goal, more-or-less, just in a different way.  Keep in mind that adjusting the MSS affects **all** TCP traffic (it doesn't affect UDP or other protocols), meaning it would affect traffic that has nothing to do with your IPsec tunnels.